# Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" only on Ipad ios

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

So, I used code from [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for rendering background video on section in web page. I faced with a problem using **only** **Ipad** Model A1490 version **ios** 9.3.2(13F69) Chrome 63.03239.73 or Safari (and iphone 6): `Blocked a frame with origin “https://www.youtube.com” from accessing a frame with origin "https://mydomain-without-leading-www.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

In the result, I can see background video as black rectangle which has loading indicator:
[image with black loading indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO4f5.jpg)

But on other devices - **desktop or android phones/tablets** - all works fine. How I use youtube api:

```
if ($('.videoplayer-container').length > 0) {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var playersArray = [];
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    var playerDefaults = {
      autoplay: 1,
      autohide: 1,
      modestbranding: 1,
      rel: 0,
      showinfo: 0,
      controls: 0,
      disablekb: 1,
      enablejsapi: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3
    };

    $('.videoplayer-container').each(function(key, value){
      var playerId = 'videoplayer-container-' + $(value).attr('data-section');
      var divObj = value;
      var playerObj = new YT.Player( playerId,
        { videoId: $(value).attr('data-youtube-id'),
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onStateChange
          },
          playerVars: playerDefaults
        });
      playersArray.push({ playerId, playerObj, divObj });
    });

    function onPlayerReady(obj){
      if (obj.target.mute) {
        obj.target.mute();
      }
      playersArray.forEach(function(obj){
        const playerObject = obj.playerObj;
        if (playerObject.playVideo) {
          playerObject.playVideo();
          if (playerObject.isMuted && !playerObject.isMuted()) {
            playerObject.mute();
          }
        }
        rescaleVideo(obj);
      });
    }

    function onStateChange(obj){
      if (obj.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        obj.target.playVideo();
      }
    }

    //  ....
  };
}
```

I tried to use origin parameter and pass different values: 'https://www.youtube.com' - don't output console error, but iframe isn't created, `location.protocol + '//' + location.host` - error remains. I googled about this problem, but didn't find solving of it.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm having the same issues running OS 9.5

Comment: @Fripo Sorry. But no, I didn't. I faced with such information - https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/ and nothing more.